# How do you dynamically populate a PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> collection?

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory

I'm doing some unit testing and I need to create a test collection of the type `PrincipalSearchResult<Principal>`.  This collection is normally returned when you use the method call `UserPrincipal.GetAuthorizationGroups()`.

This type is part of the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` namepsace which houses code for querying Microsoft's Active Directory.

If I try to simply create a new collection like such, I get an error:

```
PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> restResult = new PrincipalSearchResult<Principal>();
```

> *Error message: `PrincipalSearchResult<Principal>` does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments.*

But I'm not getting any Intellisense when newing-up the collection that indicates what parameters to pass the constructor.

How can I create and populate this type?

Comment: `PrincipalSearchResult` does not have a publicly available constructor. that class is usually returned from searches which would initialize the class internally. I would suggest abstracting the expected result type to `IEnumerable<T>` so that it is easier to mock when testing.

Comment: Yes, as hinted by @Nkosi, there is no constructor available; you need to create an IEnumerable<Principal> for mocking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following suggestions provided in comments, I simply created a wrapper method that returned the `PrincipalSearchResult<Principal>` type cast to `IEnumerable<Principal>` for mocking.